# PyInstaller - add Excel and JPEG File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyinstaller, executable

I am trying to make a Windows executable and attach two files to the program; namely, an Excel *.xlsx* and an Image *.jpeg*.

Within the script, whenever I need to load the file, I added the following code:

```
# For the Excel
import os
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    df_db = pd.read_excel(io=os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "filename.xlsx"))
else:
    df_db =  pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

# for the image
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    img = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "Logo.jpeg")
else:
    img =  "Logo.jpeg"
```

Ultimately, to deploy the program, I run the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile ^ --add-data="filename.xlsx;." ^ --add-data="Logo.jpeg;." ^ python_main_script.py
```

And it creates an executable that correctly works; however, as I try to run the command in the code that is supposed to load the first file - the image comes after in the sequence - it raises the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\MEI35922\\filename.xlsx
```

How can I solve this issue?